# Перехват трафика с точки доступа Android

Tags: android

Есть обычный Android-смартфон, и возможность писать на java(или на чем-то ещё, если нужно). Цель: перехват трафика проходящего через мою точку доступа WiFi, с помощью самописной утилиты, которая будет функционировать без pc рядом.

Интересует и также поможет в решении:

1. Возможно ли это?
2. Существуют ли какие-то уже готовые,
   подходящие утилиты?
3. Есть ли у кого-то похожий опыт, и каков он?
4. Отличается ли перехват трафика непосредственно с этого же устройства, от перехвата с точки доступа?